# Nom des petites portes ouvertes dans une grande

Tags: vocabulaire

Les portes cochères et les portails comportent parfois une porte plus petite permettant à un piéton d'entrer sans qu'il soit nécessaire d'ouvrir les grandes portes et ce même si l'architecte n'a pas prévu d'autre entrée.  Il me semble qu'il y a un nom qui désigne spécifiquement ces petites portes ouvertes dans des plus grandes.

Ce n'est pas un portillon qui est normalement ouvert vers le haut ni une poterne qui est une porte dérobée dans une forteresse et ni le [dictionnaire électronique des synonymes](http://www.crisco.unicaen.fr/des/) ni ses concurrents [ici](http://www.synonymes.com) ou [là](http://www.dictionnaire-synonymes.com) ne m'aident à retrouver ce terme qui persiste à m'échapper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Le terme exact est ***guichet***

> Le guichet désignait une ouverture pour le passage des piétons dans une porte cochère, un petit battant en découpe dans un grand battant. ([Wikipedia : *Guichet (Architecture)*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guichet_%28architecture%29))
>
> A. − Vieilli
>   1. Petite porte pratiquée dans un portail, dans une muraille permettant le passage de quelqu'un. ([TLF : *Guichet*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/guichet))

Il est signalé comme vieilli, il est vrai qu'on ne l'entend pas tous les jours. L'Académie ne le signale pas

> 1. Petite porte pratiquée dans une plus grande ([Académie, IX<sup>ème></sup> : *Guichet*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/guichet))

Pour les ressources : dans les cas difficiles, l'outil de proxémie [PROX](http://www.cnrtl.fr/proxemie/) disponible sur le site du CNRTL est un allié fidèle, même si je me suis rendu compte après avoir trouvé qu'il suffisait d'aller voir [*porte cochère*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porte_coch%C3%A8re) sur Wikipédia.

Comment: Et il se trouvait dans les dictionnaires des synonymes, mais j'ai eu l'orgueil de ne pas en vérifier les sens comme je l'avais fait pour portillon ou poterne.

Comment: Et le [Le Dictionnaire Pratique de Menuiserie](http://justinstorck.free.fr/p/porte.php) cité par Wikipédia donne [_portillon_](http://justinstorck.free.fr/p/portillon.php) comme synonyme.

Answer (score 0):

Pour compléter la réponse d'Evpok. Un [autre synonyme de "guichet"](https://lebonsynonyme.fr/synonyme/guichet) est "judas", qui correspond à une "petite ouverture pratiquée dans un plancher, un mur, une porte, pour épier sans être vu."